# DEFF for complex surveys

Tags: r

I am trying to understand what is the difference between the design effect (DEFF) calculated with svymean and svytotal from the survey package in R.

Can anyone help?

Comment: If you want a statistical comparison, you should probably ask instead at [stats.se]. Otherwise you should post a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that shows what functions you are running and what results you are getting.

Comment: I already have my result through svymean as I cross-checked the results in STATA. I am new to R and STATA has only one command to estimate deff while R has several ways and I wanted to understand the difference between the deff calculated via  svymean,  svytotal and possibly svyciprop. I can't find this information anywhere other than very generic statements.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.